# Targetting <li> inside of other <li> - Data-id to input field on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think this is rather simple, but after trying a lot of different things, I hope you can help me.

I have a simple menu structure, and when a "li" is clicked i would like the data-id value to be passed to a input field. I can get this to work just fine, but i am having trouble with the underlying "li'es". Because they are "surrounded" by the "main" "li" and therefore the data-id from this "li" will be selected even though it is not the one i click.

Please see example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/g35banrp/1/

It works fine if you click for example Production, Technique or Option1, but if you click "country" or "dealer" if will select "Sales". 
I get why it does this but cant seem to fix it.

I've tried using the .closest selector but it didn't seem to help any. 
Any hints, pointers or links are much appreciated :)

Best regards,
Peter

Script:

```
$('li.document').on('click',function(){var content= $(this).attr("data-id")$('#test').val(content);});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `.stopPropagation()` method: http://jsfiddle.net/g35banrp/2/

```
$('li.document').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var content = $(this).attr("data-id")
    $('#test').val(content);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ prevents the event from bubbling in the parent/child relationship.

Comment: AWESOME! 
Thank you so much, can see that both this solution and the other one posted here works, is one more "correct" than the other? :)

Comment: e.preventDefault() is typically used to prevent an elements default event from firing. Like making a link no longer act as a link, or a button trigger an  ajax call. e.stopPropagation() was designed literally for this case. To stop the event from bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

You want the exact target for your click, so pass an event and use `event.target` to get the correct `li`.

```
$('li.document').on('click',function(event){
    var content = $(event.target).attr("data-id")
    $('#test').val(content);
});
```

Comment: AWESOME! 
Thank you so much, can see that both this solution and the other one posted here works, is one more "correct" than the other? :)

Comment: But are equally good :) I think `event.target` is more versatile, since it doesn't stop propagation so in some cases thats better. But sometimes you want it to stop propagating, so... Either way.

Comment: I highly doubt it, but when in doubt go for the one with the most votes I guess. I mean, I _would_ tell you to accepty mine because who doesn't like a reputation boost? But I'm not that greedy. Well, I am, but it's up to you. Also, I did just tell you to accept mine. In a cheeky way :).

Comment: Thanks! :) Sorry I couldn't accept both answers, so I went for the one with the most votes! Thanks again to both of you! :D

Comment: NNNNNNNNNNNNIOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooo! [Dramatic camera zooming out overhead] ;)